# Find files that match the regex pattern

Tags: regex, file, groovy

I need to find all files that match a particular pattern in grails.

The files will be labeled as "runid.started.xml". So I'm looking to find all using the following regex:

```
/(? <=\.)(.*?)(?=\.)/
```

I can find all files but I need to likit it to files the match the pattern. I found a few examples but none seem to work. This is the latest:

```
New File (c:\\mydirectory\\test ).eachFileRecurse (Files)
{
  if (it.name ==~ /(? <=\.)(.*?)(?=\.)/){
    println it
   {
      println "nope"
    }
```

This returns "nope"... I'm very new to grails so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. My regex seems correct in an online regex tester but I may be wrong.

Comment: Any chance you could edit this _not on your phone_, to get rid of the strange typos, and give examples of exactly what files should pass or fail?

Comment: Not at the moment..pretty much any file in the given directory with .started. in the file name should be returned.. 1234.started. xml, blahblah.started.txt, 9876.started.doc..they will all be xml but I'm just saying any file with .started. in the file name should pass all else should be ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==~` is a *match* operator. Meaning the string in question must be an exact match. And `(? <=\.)(.*?)(?=\.)` [doesn't match](https://regex101.com/r/yM5cA9/1) "runid.started.xml". So you have two options:

1. Use the *search* operator in your if statement: `=~`
2. Write a regex that [*exactly* matches](https://regex101.com/r/pQ8dD1/1) all the file names something like: `\w*\.(\w+)\.\w*`

Comment: Thanks..something so small..just shows how new I am to grails and groovy..thanks

Comment: @bryannafegar No problem, most people that use regexs have made this mistake at one time or another. If you could, when you get access to a computer, just clean up the code in your question. Ideally this would be helpful to future readers, it'd be sad if they disregarded the question over a typo in the question syntax.